# Instantly replay audio on keydown()

Tags: jquery, audio, playback, keydown

I'm trying to play audio when pressing keys on the keyboard. For some reason, I cannot replay one and the same sound until the audio file has finished playing.

Here's my html setup:

```
<audio id="65" src="assets/sounds/tom.wav"></audio>
<audio id="83" src="assets/sounds/tink.wav"></audio>
<audio id="68" src="assets/sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
...
```

and the jQuery

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
var code = e.which;
$("#"+code).get(0).play();
});
```

So, if tom.wav is 4sec long, I can hammer "A" on the keyboard as many times as I want to. It won't play again before those 4sec have passed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restart an audio file you need to first pause it, then set it's `currentTime` to `0`, before making it play again. Try this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  var audio = $('#' + e.which)[0];
  audio.pause();
  audio.currentTime = 0;
  audio.play();
});
```

Comment: Great. Thanks! Works like a charm.